# Creating dataframe from *args series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I read a csv file and create a dataframe.

```
Date  Region  Measure1  Measure2
02/21 North   0.8765    12562
04/21 North   0.1723    21861
06/21 South   0.9617    17308
```

I then want to write a function that takes in a few columns from this data frame as *args and groups that data by a dimension column to calculate the average. I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
measure_col = df['Measure1']
col1 = df['Date']
col2 = df['Region']

# Average Function
def avg(measure, *cols):
    cols = list(cols)
    data = pd.DataFrame([measure, cols], axis=1)
    return data.groupby(cols)[measure].transform("mean")

print(avg(measure_col, col1, col2))
```

My aim here is to make a dataframe with just the arguments given to the avg function. The above code results in a TypeError as it cannot concatenate the type list but only Series or DataFrame. If I don't convert to list I am not able to pass it groupby. How can I get the required dataframe inside the function?

```
Date  Region  Measure1  
02/21 North   0.8765    
04/21 North   0.1723    
06/21 South   0.9617
```

thank you

Comment: Replace "[measure, cols]" by "[measure] + cols".

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! this created the dataframe :) But how do I calculate the average after that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the average calculation? If there is an error message show it completely as properly formatted text in the question along with the (now modified) code that caused it.